# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. (build problem in android studio)

Tags: android, gradle, build

yesterday i started a new project in android studio but could not build it successfully . i tried to troubleshoot, so did as below :

build gradle in offline mode .

add mavenCentral() in build.gradle .

add google() in build.gradle .

invalidate caches and restart .

try using VPN.

the only way which i solved the problem was : using " classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'" instead of "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'".

but whenever i use gradle:4.0.1 there is a warning which say's you should update gradle plugin to 4.1.1 .
I DON"T KNOW WHY IT DOESN'T BUILD WITH GRADLE:4.1.1 .
Android studio version : 4.1.1

any ideas ...

[image]

[image]

[image]